# Sorting data from database in laravel

Tags: javascript, php

Hello i have app which display data from mysql database in table.App is made in Laravel. I would like to sort this data by clicking column name. I'm trying to do this with javascript but its not working. Is something wrong with function?

This is my table which display from mysql

```
<p><button onclick="sortTable()">Posortuj</button></p>

 <table classname="sorting">

                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Test</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach ($get_all_examples as $post)
                        <tr>
                            @php
                                $user_id = Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier();
                               $cek_tiket = DB::table('test')
                        
                                    ->where('date', '!=', null)
                                    ->where('numbery', '=', $post->name)
                                    ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                                    ->count()
                                    
                            @endphp
                            <td>{{ $post->name?? "brak" }} </td>
                            <td>{{ $post->example ?? "brak" }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $post->number ?? "brak" }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $post->date ?? "brak" }}</td>
                            <td><h3>{{$cek_tiket}}</h3></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And this is my js code which i want to sort my table:

```
<script>
    function sortTable(n) {
        var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
        table = document.getElementsByClassName("sorting");
        switching = true;
        // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
        dir = "asc";
        /* Make a loop that will continue until
        no switching has been done: */
        while (switching) {
            // Start by saying: no switching is done:
            switching = false;
            rows = table.rows;
            /* Loop through all table rows (except the
            first, which contains table headers): */
            for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                // Start by saying there should be no switching:
                shouldSwitch = false;
                /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
                one from current row and one from the next: */
                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
                based on the direction, asc or desc: */
                if (dir == "asc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                        // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (dir == "desc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                        // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (shouldSwitch) {
                /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
                and mark that a switch has been done: */
                rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                switching = true;
                // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
                switchcount ++;
            } else {
                /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
                set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
                if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                    dir = "desc";
                    switching = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First in your html,  change `<table classname="sorting">`    to `<table class="sorting">` next in your javascript change  `table = document.getElementsByClassName("sorting");`  to  `table = document.getElementsByClassName("sorting")[0];`  then it will work.

Comment: I change it but in console i get an error: "raport:2876 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML') at sortTable (raport:2876) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (raport:352)"

Comment: It seems that your JS has no access to the element. This may be due to the fact that you have the JS in header. If this is the case, move the js code to the bottom, just before the closing body tag.

Comment: you call  `<p><button onclick="sortTable()">Posortuj</button></p>`  without specifying the `n`   for  `sortTable`.